# Connect-PnPOnline using ClientId and self-signed certificate

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, certificate, aad

Does anyone know how to `Connect-PnPOnline` using Azure AD APP permissions and a self-signed certificate?

Steps:

- Generated a self-signed certificate. Recorded the password
- Registered an Azure App. Uploaded a certificate to the app
- Granted App permissions to the app
- Granted admin consent

[image]

Now, I am trying to `connect-PnPOnline` using the script below:

```
    $certificatePassword = 'CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD'
    $secureCertificatePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $certificatePassword -AsPlainText -Force

    Connect-PnPOnline `
        -CertificatePath "C:\...\DeploymentApp.pfx" `
        -Tenant <TENANT>.onmicrosoft.com `
        -ClientId fff6667e-1141-4bb5-ba3e-eaaf653975c6 `
        -Url https://<TENANT>.sharepoint.com `
        -CertificatePassword $secureCertificatePass `
        -IgnoreSslErrors
```

I'm getting an unhelpful error:

> Connect-PnPOnline : Exception has been thrown by the target of an
>   invocation. At line:5 char:1
>   + Connect-PnPOnline `
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-PnPOnline], TargetInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException,SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline

Using the latest PowerShell PnP Module: SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 3.13.1909.0

Can someone recommend something, please?

**Update**

[Found related issue with no resolution yet.](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2181)

**Update**

You can try to easily replicate my case:

- Get [these scripts](https://gist.github.com/Zerg00s/848e5a7bde46c20254dff377b6a5b6d2) on your local folder.
- [Install Azure CLI on Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest).
- Right-click on Register_AD_App.bat and "run as administrator".
- You will be promted to enter an admin account for your Azure AD/Office 365.
- At the end the app will be registered, consent granted to the SharePoint API permissions.
- o365AppDetails.json file will be created that contains an auto-generated certificate password. You can use this password for the script for the `-CertificatePassword` param of the `Connect-PnPOnline` commandlet.

[image]

**Update:**

I maged to make it work using `Thumbprint` instead of the `CertificatePath`:
    Connect-PnPOnline 
        `-Thumbprint '637C2635E1E4478FB48A643B6EEB7F7C8920B7E4'`
        -Tenant tenant.onmicrosoft.com 
        `-ClientId fff6667e-1141-4bb5-ba3e-eaaf653975c6`
        -Url https://tenant.sharepoint.com

But I'm still curious to know how to make CertificatePath work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to use -CertificatePath by referencing the .cer file instead of the .pfx.

In my case I am using the latest PnP 3.16.1912.0 but now get an error when trying to use the -Thumbprint . . . https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/issues/2181.